# Selection Sort by alternate selection

Tags: python, list, selection-sort

I am solving the following code challenge:

> Let N be the size of a list. Implement the *Selection Sort* algorithm with the following modifications:
>
> - In odd iterations, find the element with the lowest value and place it in the location adequate.
> - In even iterations, find the element with the highest value and place it in the location adequate.
>   With each iteration, print the state of the list. Perform N – 1 iterations.
>
> The input is composed of two lines, the first with the list size and the second with the list elements.

This is my code:

```py
def ordenacao_por_selecao_modificada(arr):
    n = len(arr)

    for i in range(1,n):
        
        if i % 2 == 0:
            # Nas iterações pares, encontre o elemento com o maior valor
            indice_maior = i
            for j in range(i, len(arr)):
                if arr[j] > arr[indice_maior]:
                    indice_maior = j
            print(lista)
            arr[i],arr[indice_maior] = arr[indice_maior],arr[i]
        else:
            # Nas iterações ímpares, encontre o elemento com o menor valor
            indice_menor = i
            for j in range(i, n):
                if arr[j] < arr[indice_menor]:
                    indice_menor = j
            print(lista)
            arr[i], arr[indice_menor] = arr[indice_menor], arr[i]


lista = [8, 2, 5, 1, 10, 4]
ordenacao_por_selecao_modificada(lista)
```

When I make the implementation change between odd or even, I can get the expected result, however, when I add the condition, the results are still out of order after each change.

An example of the output with checking for even or odd:

```
[1, 2, 5, 8, 10, 4] 
[1, 10, 5, 8, 2, 4]
[1, 10, 2, 8, 5, 4]
[1, 10, 2, 8, 5, 4] 
[1, 10, 2, 8, 4, 5]
```

The list should be sorted at the end. What is my mistake?

Comment: Hi, what is the question?

Comment: When I make the implementation change between odd or even, I can get the expected result, however, when I add the condition, the results are still out of order after each change, an example of the output with checking for even or odd
[1, 2, 5, 8, 10, 4]
[1, 10, 5, 8, 2, 4]
[1, 10, 2, 8, 5, 4]
[1, 10, 2, 8, 5, 4]
[1, 10, 2, 8, 4, 5]

There is some part of the code that I can't identify why this is happening

Comment: I reverted the edits you did to the question, which removed essential information, such as the purpose of the code, and where you introduced the term "linked list" in the title, which obfuscates what this question really is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main mistake is that `i` is not the place where the swap must occur:

It should be a completely different index in odd iterations than in even iterations. In odd iterations that index should be 0 (for first iteration), 1 (for third iteration), 2 (for fifth iteration), ... And for even iterations that index should n −1 (for second iteration), −2 (for fourth iteration), ...etc, so this is generally *not* the value of `i`

You should also adapt the range to search for the minimum/maximum. As iterations occur, the right side of the array also gets a sorted segment, and so the search should not go all the way to the end of the array.

It will be easier if you maintain the leftmost and rightmost index of the segment that is not sorted yet. This window will get smaller and smaller as iterations are made.

Here is the corrected code:

```py
def ordenacao_por_selecao_modificada(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    left = 0
    right = n - 1
    for i in range(1,n):
        if i % 2 == 1:
            indice_maior = right
            for j in range(left, right + 1):
                if arr[j] > arr[indice_maior]:
                    indice_maior = j
            print(lista)
            arr[right], arr[indice_maior] = arr[indice_maior], arr[right]
            right -= 1
        else:
            indice_menor = left
            for j in range(left, right + 1):
                if arr[j] < arr[indice_menor]:
                    indice_menor = j
            print(lista)
            arr[left], arr[indice_menor] = arr[indice_menor], arr[left]
            left += 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I will continue studying selection sort/data structure, if you have or know of any YouTube channel or study material, could you recommend it?